# Trying to Make mini Jeopardy flash game button help pls

Tags: flash, button, visible

Hey im a noob in flash cs3 and i want to create a jeopardy game where when a button is pressed we go in to the main question scene and when we come back the button the we pressed is now disabled via 'button._visible=flase'...pls any help...any suggestions or links to tutorials or tutorials from you guys or girls will grateful thanx...

Answer (score 0):

More info would be helpful. Are you using Actionscript 2 or 3? Is the problem that the button is not hiding properly? Do you have any error messages in the Output window?

If the problem is with hiding the button, the AS2 code would be:

```
button._visible=false;
```

The AS3 code would be:

```
button.visible = false;
```